# ¿Cómo utilizar windows authentication utilizando EF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

tenía una consulta sobre como hacer uso de windows authentication para el login de mi aplicación usando Entity Framework. Como ya sabemos al usar el wizard para crear el objeto de EF, ahí seleccionamos como queremos que sea el inicio de sesión, sin embargo, crea la cadena de conexión en el web.conf. La pregunta concreta es ¿cómo puedo pasar mi usuario y contraseña a ese archivo xml? ¿o acaso tengo que crear una cadena de conexión aparte? Es primera vez que tengo que hacer uso de un inicio de sesión así.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no es precisamente lo que necesitaba pero igual me sirve y espero les sirva a ustedes.

En mi caso, lo que necesito es validar que estos usuarios existen en SQLSERVER, no dentro de la base de datos, si no en la seguridad que este tiene.

Entonces lo que logre leyendo fue lo siguiente:

```
var originalConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadenaDeConexión"].ConnectionString;
var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(originalConnectionString);
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(entityBuilder.Provider);
var providerBuilder = factory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder();

providerBuilder.ConnectionString = entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString;
providerBuilder.Add("user id", "prueba");
providerBuilder.Add("password", "asdf");
entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerBuilder.ToString();
```

De esta manera, accedemos a la cadena de conexión y la modificamos, pasando los debidos parametros. Luego, con un simple try catch, verificamos que la conexión haya sido correcta y si no pues no le damos acceso al usuario.

Espero les sirva!

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando autenticación Windows, en tu cadena de conexión debe aparecer el atributo "Trusted_Connection=Yes" o también el atributo "Integrated Security=True". Mayor información en https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero no es lo que buscaba.